# How make a complete gui softwaree in a single windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Actually i m making a hospital management GUI software.
But there is some problems are arise , when i login as a admin then it will open a new window and when i click any button then it will again open a  new window. 
So i want that there will be only a root window and when i press any button then just the frame will change but window will remain same root.
I had used destroy() and tk.raies() as well but when i use these then old window will destroy and that will never come back.
So please suggest me a code for frame switching in a same root windows. And when i switch the frame the old frame will go disappear and can come back when it will call.

Comment: There are many questions on this site related to switching between frames or switching between windows. Have you read them? I doubt we can give different answers on how to switch between frames than what is already on this site.

Answer (score -1):

To update without changing the window, you basically have to use the after method, if you use it the correct way, then it will be able update automatically. Here is an example:

```
def someKindOfFunction():
    #something happening there
    window.after(100,someKindOfFunction)
someKindOfFunction()
```

This way you will create a loop, you would then have to specify conditions for when you are on the login and where you are not.